# Is there a way to ensure that the bars in a Chart do not get cut off when they are displayed?

Tags: chart.js

A client of mine is using chart.js plugins to configure charts on a document which they are electronically generating.

So, their current requirement is to avoid the spacing between 0 - 2018 as shown in **Figure 1** (below).

In order to obtain this requirement when we search on chartjs configuration we find that the offset option that meets our requirements which should be set to false, but it returns half of the bar graph at the beginning and end as shown in **Figure 2** (below).

Please note: The client requirement is fixed to the **Figure 2** for which they will require the complete bar graph and **not **the partial one.

Figure 1:

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSck9.png)

Figure 2:

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMh79.png)

Is there a way to ensure that perhaps in the Chart.js configuration to ensure that the bars do not display/render this way?

Thanks

The offset in the chart.js configuration was set to "false" which should return the desired outcome, however this is not the case.